# How can I edit the header of a Google Sites webpage?

Tags: html, google-sites

My website has a header. I am able to edit the HTML content of each of other pages. However I am not able to edit the HTML content of the header. It does appear when I select view page source but I am still unable to edit. The website was created using Google Sites.

Answer (score 0):

We could hide the header, edit its appearance through the Google Sites user interface, but we could not edit the site header's HTML.

For further details see:

- [Change your site's  appearance](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97520?hl=en)
- [Change your site's layout](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/187377?hl=en)